# How to feed existing markers into a marker cluster in GoogleMap iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am developing an app using Google Map iOS SDK (Objective C).

Done so far:

- Loaded markers from the server in map view
- Generate random clusters only.

When I run the project it looks like this.

[Screen shot of map view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiSik.png)

It shows both markers and clusters both in the map view at zoom level 10. But I wanted to show clusters first then when I zoomed in it should show the real markers. Not the randomly generated markers that I created because I don't know a way to show the clusters in the map.

Here is the full code with fake URL link:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
//#import "CSMarker.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <Google-Maps-iOS-Utils/GMUMarkerClustering.h>

//importing POI Item object - points of interest

@interface POIItem : NSObject<GMUClusterItem>

@property(nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D position;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *name;

- (instancetype)initWithPosition:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)position name:(NSString *)name;

@end

@implementation POIItem

- (instancetype)initWithPosition:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)position name:(NSString *)name {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _position = position;
        _name = [name copy];
    }
    return self;
}

@end

//implementation start - map view controller

static const NSUInteger kClusterItemCount = 60;
static const double kCameraLatitude = 25.277683999999997;
static const double kCameraLongitude = 55.309802999999995;

@interface ViewController ()<GMUClusterManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate>
{

    NSMutableArray *waypoints_;
    NSMutableArray *waypointStrings_;
    GMSMapView *_mapView;
    GMUClusterManager *_clusterManager;



}
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSURLSession *markerSession;
@property(strong, nonatomic) GMSMapView *mapView;
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSSet *markers;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *markersArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize gs;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:kCameraLatitude
                                                            longitude:kCameraLongitude
                                                                 zoom:10];

    self.mapView =
    [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];

    self.mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
    self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;

    //setup the cluster manager



    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config =
    [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    config.URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:2 * 1024 * 1024
                                                    diskCapacity:10 * 1024 * 1024
                                                        diskPath:@"MarkerData"];
    self.markerSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    [self downloadMarkerData];

    //cluster load setup

    id<GMUClusterAlgorithm> algorithm = [[GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm alloc] init];
    id<GMUClusterIconGenerator> iconGenerator = [[GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator alloc] init];
    id<GMUClusterRenderer> renderer =
    [[GMUDefaultClusterRenderer alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView
                                  clusterIconGenerator:iconGenerator];
    _clusterManager =
    [[GMUClusterManager alloc] initWithMap:self.mapView algorithm:algorithm renderer:renderer];

    // Generate and add random items to the cluster manager.
    [self generateClusterItems];

    // Call cluster() after items have been added to perform the clustering and rendering on map.
    [_clusterManager cluster];

    // Register self to listen to both GMUClusterManagerDelegate and GMSMapViewDelegate events.
    [_clusterManager setDelegate:self mapDelegate:self];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (NSMutableArray *)markersArray
{
    if (!_markersArray) {
        _markersArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return _markersArray;
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//downloading marker data

- (void)downloadMarkerData {

    NSURL *lakesURL =
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myscrap.com/xxx.php/webservice/xxx/xxxx"];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.markerSession dataTaskWithURL:lakesURL
                                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *e)
                                  {

                                      NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                      options:0
                                                                                        error:nil];
                                      NSLog(@"json: %@",json);

                                      [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                                      [self createMarkerObjectsWithJson:json];

                                      }];


                                  }];
    [task resume];
}

-(void)drawMarkers
{
    for(GMSMarker *marker in self.markers) {

        if(marker.map == nil) {
            marker.map = self.mapView;
        }

    }
}




-(void)createMarkerObjectsWithJson:(NSArray *)json
{


    NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithSet:self.markers];

    for (NSDictionary *markerData in json) {

        GMSMarker *newMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
       // newMarker.appearAnimation = [markerData[@"id"] integerValue];

        newMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([markerData[@"latitud"] doubleValue],
                                                        [markerData[@"longitude"] doubleValue]);

        newMarker.title = markerData[@"name"];
        newMarker.snippet = markerData[@"adress"];

      //  [mutableSet addObject:newMarker];
        newMarker.map=self.mapView;

    }
    self.markers =[mutableSet copy];
    [self drawMarkers];

}

#pragma mark GMUClusterManagerDelegate

- (void)clusterManager:(GMUClusterManager *)clusterManager didTapCluster:(id<GMUCluster>)cluster {
    GMSCameraPosition *newCamera =
    [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:cluster.position zoom:_mapView.camera.zoom + 1];
    GMSCameraUpdate *update = [GMSCameraUpdate setCamera:newCamera];
    [_mapView moveCamera:update];
}

#pragma mark GMSMapViewDelegate

- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    POIItem *poiItem = marker.userData;
    if (poiItem != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Did tap marker for cluster item %@", poiItem.name);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Did tap a normal marker");
    }
    return NO;
}


#pragma mark Private

// Randomly generates cluster items within some extent of the camera and adds them to the
// cluster manager.
- (void)generateClusterItems {
    const double extent = 0.2;
    for (int index = 1; index <= kClusterItemCount; ++index) {
        double lat = kCameraLatitude + extent * [self randomScale];
        double lng = kCameraLongitude + extent * [self randomScale];
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d", index];
        id<GMUClusterItem> item =
        [[POIItem alloc] initWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng) name:name];
        [_clusterManager addItem:item];
    }
}

// Returns a random value between -1.0 and 1.0.
- (double)randomScale {
    return (double)arc4random() / UINT32_MAX * 2.0 - 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing in view did load

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:kCameraLatitude longitude:kCameraLongitude zoom:4];
```

the zoom to a 5 or 4. It then should show the clusters and not the markers. When you zoom in, it will show the "real" markers.